# Redux retorna undefined estado

Tags: reactjs, redux

tengo un problema,
tengo una aplicación que hace llamado a una api, y utiliza redux para el estado de la aplicación, el llamado a la api esta funcionando bien, el problema es cuando quiero pasar ese estado a un componente por medio de props, cuando hago eso todo se rompe, que puedo hacer?,
gracias

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(()=>{
    //consulta api
    const cargarProducto=()=>dispatch(obtenerProductosAction())
    cargarProducto()
},[])
const productos = useSelector(state=>state.productos.productos)
const error = useSelector(state=>state.productos.error)
const cargando = useSelector(state=>state.productos.loading)
```

la consola de productos devuelve mi arreglo que necesito:

```
 [
    {name:'manzana',
    thumb_url:'url'
    },
{name:'mango',
    thumb_url:'url'
    }
    ]
```

///hasta qui todo bien

```
<ProductoCard productoDetails={producto} className={styles.user} item={Socials} />
```

//aqui al intentar pasar el estado por props, "funciona", peero si yo doy F5 todo deja de funcionar y me devuelve este error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumb_url' of undefined

si quito mi componente ProductoCard puedo dar f5 cuantas veces quiera y todo funciona.

datos en componente ProductoCard:

```
const User = ({ productoDetails }) => {
return (
<div className={styles.avatar}>
          <img src={productoDetails.thumb_url} alt="Avatar" />
        </div>
<p>{productoDetails.name}</p>
)
}
```

Comment: En `productoDetails={producto}` estas pasando una variable `producto`, ¿Eso esta bien o mas bien se esta pasando `productos` que traes con `useSelector`? . Ahora `thumb_url` viene dentro de `productos` y si es asi, ¿Como esta inicializada en tu init `state`?

Comment: ya actualize mi pregunta con los datos, asi es, se esta pasando productos que viene con useSelector

Comment: si, esta en el reducer: initialState={productos:[],loading:false,error:false},user era de un componente reciclar, pero el nombre ya lo habia corregido

Answer (score 1):

En tu componente ProductCard estas recibiendo productoDetails, el cual corresponde a una lista:

```js
[
    {name:'manzana',
    thumb_url:'url'
    },
{name:'mango',
    thumb_url:'url'
    }
    ]
```

Lo correcto sería crear una instancia de ProductCard por cada elemento de tu lista o si quieres validar el comportamiento, puedes pasar el primer elemento de la lista. Comparto ambos ejemplos:

// prueba con el primer elemento

```js
<ProductoCard productoDetails={productos[0]} className={styles.user} item={Socials} />
```

// crear una instancia por cada elemento

```js
return ({productos.map((producto) => (<ProductoCard productoDetails={producto} className={styles.user} item={Socials} />))
})
```

**Con respecto al error**: "Cannot read property 'thumb_url' of undefined"

En tu ejemplo estas pasando como argumento "producto", siendo que tu lista se llama "productos", por lo tanto estas pasando nada, mucho menos podrás a acceder a una propiedad llamada "thumb_url" de nada, es decir: undefined

Comment: con.map funciona, pero existe una forma de pasar el estado de redux sin que se pieerda cuando presiono f5? si no tendre que usar map en todas mis llamadas

Comment: Puedes persistir el estado para prevenir que se pierda tras refrescar. Esto ya se discutió aquí:

[React Redux state is lost at page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161128/react-redux-state-is-lost-at-page-refresh)

Comment: muchas gracias!